# Apache using TLS1.0 even if configure with TLS1.2

Tags: apache, openssl, tls1.2

I have issues when to make my apache server uses TLS1.2. I respect all recommended configuration (ssl.conf, virtuals, ciphers ...) but apache is all the time using TLS1.0. I suspect the version of openssl to be the root cause.
Environment : RHEL 7
openssl version : OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips
Apache version : Apache/2.4.6
I have this message on browser dev tools even though configuration seems to be ok :

```
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.0, ECDHE_RSA, and AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1.
TLS 1.0 is obsolete. Enable TLS 1.2 or later.
AES_256_CBC is obsolete. Enable an AES-GCM-based cipher suite.
```

can you help on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have restarted apache.

And, make sure this line is added, and make sure all other `SSLProtocol` are commented using `#` at the start of the line, or removed:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

Or, if your version of OpenSSL doesn't support TLSv1.3:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

I absolutely recommend you to update to the latest version of Apache (2.4.46 at the time of this post), and OpenSSL 1.1.1.

You can use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com) to test your website's SSL conf.

Next:

> AES_256_CBC is obsolete. Enable an AES-GCM-based cipher suite.

For the above, you can test your site on SSL Labs, and see the ciphers that are green and orange, and you can implement them by using https://testssl.sh/openssl-iana.mapping.html for help

Comment: @kylebb, then your openssl might not support tls 1.2

Comment: @kylebb did you restart apache?

Comment: @kylebb are you sure you don't have any other conf saying that `SSLProtocol` directive?

Comment: this is my virtualhost ssl section conf :
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA

  SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2

  SSLCertificateFile      "/etc/httpd/certificates/xxxxx.cer"

  SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/etc/httpd/certificates/xxxxx.key"

  SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/httpd/certificates/xxxx.txt"

Comment: @kylebb put `SSLProtocol` out side virtualhost, and try

Comment: I put it outside but same issue. it is really strange ...

Comment: @kylebb did you restart apache?

Comment: yes  I restart it every time I perform a modification

Comment: Try using `grep -rnw . -e 'SSLProtocol'` in the apache conf folder

Comment: /etc/httpd/mods-available/ssl.conf:68:  SSLProtocol all -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3
/etc/httpd/sites-available/jenkins-proxy.conf:16:  SSLProtocol -all T+TLSv1.2

Comment: @kylebb remove that, and only add `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3` in one place

Comment: Hello person, I try this but same resulat. I will definitely upgrade the openssl library